# Gson to json returning all the elements of subclass also

Tags: json, gson

I have a situation where the gson is returning the child object elements also when i tried to make a json string from parent object. how to eliminate the same.

Here is the code i am having.

```
Class Image {
    private int imageID;
    private String imageName;

    // Getters and setters
}

Class ImageDetails extends Image {
    private String imageType;
    private byte[] imageData;
    //Getters and setters
}


Class Test {
    // Setting the image Object, and the imageDetails.

    // calling the gson for json string
    String jsonString = GsonString.UserFeed(ImageObject)

    // This jsonString has all the elements from the ImageDetails Object also which i do not want.
}

Class GsonString {

    public static String UserFeed(Object feedData) {
        String feeds = null;
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        feeds = gson.toJson(feedData);
        return feeds;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only have to specify the class you want to serialize, using  [toJson(Object src,Type typeOfSrc)](https://google-gson.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/gson/docs/javadocs/com/google/gson/Gson.html#toJson%28java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.reflect.Type%29)

A simple example:

```
class Bob {
    private String bobName = "Bob";
}

class Pete extends Bob {
    private String peteName = "Bob";
}
```

---

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Object o = new Pete();
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(o));
    System.out.println(new Gson().toJson(o, Bob.class));

}
```

---

**Output:**

```
{"peteName":"Bob","bobName":"Bob"}
{"bobName":"Bob"}
```

Comment: what if Pete has an Object in it and that Object has a same situation of this? how do i eliminate the same inside the object.

Comment: what if Pete has an Object in it and that Object has a same situation of this? how do i eliminate the same inside the object. or in the below case if i have an array of Pete Objects, its not working. public static String UserFeed(List feedData, Class className)
 {
  String feeds = null;
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  feeds = gson.toJson(feedData, className);
  return feeds;
 }

Comment: It does not work if `o` is a list of `Pete`. how does that work with `new TypeToken<List<Bob>>()` instead of `Bob.class`?

Comment: @dbaq Generics are an special case, because class cannot be specified in that way. Anyway, it is interesting. I'll try to find  solution, thank you.